# how to create tree view in mysql using stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, tree, materialized-path-pattern

I am confused. I don't know how to create a tree view in MySQL using stored procedure. I tried searching in Google and I don't understand how to query.

I have

```
deptid  |  dept_code |  dept_name  | parent_deptid
     1             1    wadir Umum           0
     2           101   bagian umum           1
     3         10101   kepala umum           2
     4           102   bagian privasi        1
     5       1010101   SUb bagian Tu         3
     6       1010102   bagian umum           3
```

and I want to make it like this

```
deptid  |  dept_code |  dept_name  |    parent_deptid
     1             1   wadir Umum                0
     2           101   -bagian umum              1
     3         10101   --kepala umum             2
     5       1010101   ---Sub bagian Tu          3 
     6       1010102   ---bagian umum            3
     4           102   -bagian privasi           1
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data? What is your query?

Comment: Why is *deptid=5* ordered after *deptid=6* when its parentid is 3?

Comment: sorry my false edited

Answer (score 0):

Since department code pattern looks to be convenient, I didn't spent time on parent_id. According to your department code pattern, following should help.

Simply padding the dept code and getting the sortable uniform codes.

Change your tableName in query please.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY RPAD(dept_code, 5, '0')
```

EDIT: Actually if parent_deptid was the actual parent's id then you would have just needed to sort by parent_deptid, then dept_code. However, parent_deptid doesn't look like the corresponding parent's id but something like "depth" instead.

EDIT2: Sorry, your parent_deptid looks to be ok, just needed to see more data showing other parent ids too. So I missed it. All you need to sort as following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY parent_deptid, dept_code;
```

EDIT3 - According to edited question: Back to my initial suggestion by changing the padded string length - Following is the most suitable solution for your data structure.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY RPAD(dept_code, 10, '0')
```

- 10 could be the max length of your dept_code.

Comment: @HardianZ My initial answer should have helped but needed to change padding length according to your new sample data.  Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your dept_code column type to VARCHAR and use next query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY dept_code
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will create a markup output:

```sql
SELECT group_concat(
  CONCAT(
    REPEAT('    ', (CHAR_LENGTH(t.dept_code) - 1) / 2),
    '- ',
    t.dept_name
  )
  ORDER BY t.dept_code
  SEPARATOR '\n'
) AS markup
FROM Table1 t
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22019/4)

Result:

```markup
- wadir Umum
    - bagian umum
        - kepala umum
            - SUb bagian Tu
        - bagian umum
    - bagian privasi
```

Will be rendered to:

- wadir Umum

  - bagian umum

    - kepala umum

      - SUb bagian Tu
    - bagian umum
  - bagian privasi

**Update**

To match the question update:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
  CHAR_LENGTH(t.dept_code) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.dept_code, '0', '')) AS indent,
  CONCAT(
    REPEAT('-', CHAR_LENGTH(t.dept_code) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.dept_code, '0', ''))),
    t.dept_name
  ) AS indented_name
FROM Table1 t
ORDER BY t.dept_code
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18e6d/1)

**Update 2**

The benefit of your design is that you do not need a stored procedure for such tasks. See the `dept_code` as the *full tree path* with `0` as separator. `1010102` could also be written as `1/1/1/2`. If designed correctly you can just order by `dept_code`. To get node depth you just need to count the separator (`0`) in the path (`dept_code`).

**Update 3**

If you want to create a recursive structure, you better do in a procedural language like PHP:

Store SQL result from a simple query (`SELECT * FROM depts`) into an array, which would look like:

```php
// result from query: SELECT * FROM depts
$depts = array(
    array( // row #0
        'deptid' => 1,
        'dept_code' => '1',
        'dept_name' => 'wadir Umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 0,
    ),
    array( // row #1
        'deptid' => 2,
        'dept_code' => '101',
        'dept_name' => 'bagian umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 1,
    ),
    array( // row #2
        'deptid' => 3,
        'dept_code' => '10101',
        'dept_name' => 'kepala umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 2,
    ),
    array( // row #3
        'deptid' => 4,
        'dept_code' => '102',
        'dept_name' => 'bagian privasi',
        'parent_deptid' => 1,
    ),
    array( // row #4
        'deptid' => 5,
        'dept_code' => '1010101',
        'dept_name' => 'SUb bagian Tu',
        'parent_deptid' => 3,
    ),
    array( // row #5
        'deptid' => 6,
        'dept_code' => '1010102',
        'dept_name' => 'bagian umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 3,
    ),
);
```

Build a recursive structure with two `foreach` loops:

```php
$nodes = array();
$roots = array();

// init nodes
foreach ($depts as $dept) {
    $dept['childs'] = array(); // init childs
    $nodes[$dept['deptid']] = $dept;
}

foreach ($depts as $dept) {
    if ($dept['parent_deptid'] == 0) {
        $roots[] = $dept['deptid']; // add root
    } else {
        $nodes[$dept['parent_deptid']]['childs'][] = $dept['deptid']; // add to parents chlids list
    }
}
```

The arrays `$roots` and `$nodes` will look like:

```php
$roots = array (0 => 1,);
$nodes = array(
    1 => array(
        'deptid' => 1,
        'dept_code' => '1',
        'dept_name' => 'wadir Umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 0,
        'childs' => array(
            0 => 2,
            1 => 4,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    2 => array(
        'deptid' => 2,
        'dept_code' => '101',
        'dept_name' => 'bagian umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 1,
        'childs' => array(
            0 => 3,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    3 => array(
        'deptid' => 3,
        'dept_code' => '10101',
        'dept_name' => 'kepala umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 2,
        'childs' => array(
            0 => 5,
            1 => 6,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    4 => array(
        'deptid' => 4,
        'dept_code' => '102',
        'dept_name' => 'bagian privasi',
        'parent_deptid' => 1,
        'childs' => array() ,
    ) ,
    5 => array(
        'deptid' => 5,
        'dept_code' => '1010101',
        'dept_name' => 'SUb bagian Tu',
        'parent_deptid' => 3,
        'childs' => array() ,
    ) ,
    6 => array(
        'deptid' => 6,
        'dept_code' => '1010102',
        'dept_name' => 'bagian umum',
        'parent_deptid' => 3,
        'childs' => array() ,
    ) ,
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YkAr0)

Now you can write some recursive function to walk through the tree:

```php
function getSubtreeHTMLList($deptsids, $nodes) {
    $result = '<ul>';
    foreach ($deptsids as $deptsid) {
        $result .= '<li>';
        $result .= $nodes[$deptsid]['dept_name'];
        if (count($nodes[$deptsid]['childs'] > 0)) {
            $result .= getSubtreeHTMLList($nodes[$deptsid]['childs'], $nodes);
        }
        $result .= '</li>';
    }
    $result .= '</ul>';
    return $result;
}

echo getSubtreeHTMLList($roots, $nodes);
```

Created HTML:

```php
<ul><li>wadir Umum<ul><li>bagian umum<ul><li>kepala umum<ul><li>SUb bagian Tu<ul></ul></li><li>bagian umum<ul></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>bagian privasi<ul></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mnV5m)

Rendered:

- wadir Umum

  - bagian umum

    - kepala umum

      - SUb bagian Tu
      - bagian umum
  - bagian privasi

Comment: didn't work the result 
- wadir umum       - bagian umum      -kepala umum       -sub bagian tu

Comment: You need to show it in plain-text. Use the drop-down menu near the "Run SQL" button.

Comment: ok work in sql-fidle, but i still don't understand with plain-text when i want to query using php and show it in table, i using SP call treeview

Comment: The second query provides you the *indention*, which you can use in PHP to render your HTML.

Comment: ok understand thank you , but how about using parent and child with recursive?

Comment: @HardianZ, MySQL is "allergic" to anything that is recursive. You can do it much cleaner in PHP. See my update.