# Tree-Hierarchical query without stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL, is it possible to get following result in single SQL statement from below table structure?

Currently I am able to get same result by using *logical while loop in my PHP code*. It will be good if I can achieve in a single SQL, for performance.

Expected result:

```
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  Id (PK) +    headerANDsubheader                         + 
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1       +    A-head                                     +
|  4       +     -A-head-A1-subHead                        +
|  5       +     -A-head-A2-subHead                        +
|  6       +      --A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead         +
|  7       +      --A-head-A1-subHead-A1.2-subHead         +
```

Column `Id` is primary key. If parent key is 0 then it means, its root level heading.

If `ParentKey` is not equal to 0 then it means it a sub heading of someone, and `ParentKey` is a pointer for that.

Table: **Header_sub**

```
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  Id (PK) +    headerANDsubheader                         + ParentKey  +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  1       +    A-head                                     +   0        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  2       +    B-head                                     +   0        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  3       +    C-head                                     +   0        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  4       +    A-head-A1-subHead                          +   1        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  5       +    A-head-A2-subHead                          +   1        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  6       +    A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead             +   4        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  7       +    A-head-A1-subHead-A1.2-subHead             +   4        +
|----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I am trying like this ...

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(REPEAT(' ', (COUNT(parent.subject_group_name) - 1) ), node.subject_group_name) AS name
FROM 
    major_scholastic as node,
    major_scholastic as parent
WHERE 
    node.s_gid BETWEEN parent.s_gid AND parent.parent_id
GROUP BY  node.subject_group_name
ORDER BY node.s_gid
```

Comment: Why don't your table and column names from query and sample data match?

Comment: If header_sub is your actual table structure: why not just add the depth as a column when you update the path and use this in `repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `headerANDsubheader` column is some kind of *meterialized path*. That allows you to get all ancestors (not only the direct parent) by using a `JOIN` with a `LIKE` condition.

The following query demonstrates how to get the information you might need for different tasks:

```sql
select node.*
    , group_concat(anc.Id order by char_length(anc.headerANDsubheader)) as idPath
    , group_concat(lpad(anc.Id, 10, 0) order by char_length(anc.headerANDsubheader)) as idPathSortable
    , count(anc.Id) as depthLevel
    , concat(repeat('- ', count(anc.Id)-1), node.headerANDsubheader) as indendtedHeader
from header_sub node
join header_sub anc
    on node.headerANDsubheader like concat(anc.headerANDsubheader, '%')
group by node.Id
order by idPathSortable
```

The result looks like this:

```sql
| Id |             headerANDsubheader | ParentKey | idPath |                   idPathSortable | depthLevel |                    indendtedHeader |
|----|--------------------------------|-----------|--------|----------------------------------|------------|------------------------------------|
|  1 | A-head                         |         0 | 1      | 0000000001                       |          1 | A-head                             |
|  4 | A-head-A1-subHead              |         1 | 1,4    | 0000000001,0000000004            |          2 | - A-head-A1-subHead                |
|  6 | A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead |         4 | 1,4,6  | 0000000001,0000000004,0000000006 |          3 | - - A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead |
|  7 | A-head-A1-subHead-A1.2-subHead |         4 | 1,4,7  | 0000000001,0000000004,0000000007 |          3 | - - A-head-A1-subHead-A1.2-subHead |
|  5 | A-head-A2-subHead              |         1 | 1,5    | 0000000001,0000000005            |          2 | - A-head-A2-subHead                |
|  2 | B-head                         |         0 | 2      | 0000000002                       |          1 | B-head                             |
|  3 | C-head                         |         0 | 3      | 0000000003                       |          1 | C-head                             |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49cc3e/5)

Now having that it's a small step to get the result you need:

```sql
select node.Id, concat(
    repeat(' ', count(anc.Id)-1),
    repeat('-', count(anc.Id)-1),
    node.headerANDsubheader
) as indendtedHeader
from header_sub node
join header_sub anc
    on node.headerANDsubheader like concat(anc.headerANDsubheader, '%')
group by node.Id
order by group_concat(lpad(anc.Id, 10, 0) order by char_length(anc.headerANDsubheader))
```

Result:

```sql
| Id |                    indendtedHeader |
|----|------------------------------------|
|  1 | A-head                             |
|  4 |  -A-head-A1-subHead                |
|  6 |   --A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead |
|  7 |   --A-head-A1-subHead-A1.2-subHead |
|  5 |  -A-head-A2-subHead                |
|  2 | B-head                             |
|  3 | C-head                             |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49cc3e/3)

**Update:**

```sql
join header_sub anc
    on node.headerANDsubheader like concat(anc.headerANDsubheader, '%')
```

`anc` is a shortcut for "ancestor". We want to join every node with all its ancestors (including itself). The condition can be read as `anc.headerANDsubheader IS PREFIX OF node.headerANDsubheader`. So "A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead" will be joined with "A-head", "A-head-A1-subHead" and "A-head-A1-subHead-A1.1-subHead". Grouping the result by `node.id` we can use the aggregations `COUNT` to get the depth level and `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate a usefull path. However it would be better to store the depth and path in the table, so we wouldn't need the join at all.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But what if my  headerANDsubheader like below. If I change data as below its not working. Can it be on Id rather than headerANDsubheader value?                 
INSERT INTO Header_sub
    (`Id`, `headerANDsubheader`, `ParentKey`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A head', 0),
    (2, 'B head', 0),
    (3, 'C head', 0),
    (4, 'subHead', 1),
    (5, 'A2 subHead', 1),
    (6, 'A1.1 subHead', 4),
    (7, 'A1.2 subHead', 4)

Comment: Then it will not work. You either add a column to your table which will store the path (like `idPath` or better `idPathSortable ` in my example) or you will need a (recursive) PHP solution. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37254368/5563083) you can find such a function (last part), which creates a nested HTML list using only one simple SQL query.

Comment: Ok, got your point. Can you let me know how this part of query works ... join header_sub anc
    on node.headerANDsubheader like concat(anc.headerANDsubheader, '%').    Why LIKE concat(anc.headerANDsubheader, '%'), why not = instead of like

Comment: See the **Update**. `=` would only join every node with itself.